# How to forward fill by group and conditional on other columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements, ffill

The original dataset is:

| Group | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1990 | NaN |
| A | 1992 | 1 |
| A | 1995 | NaN |
| A | 1997 | NaN |
| A | 1998 | NaN |
| A | 2001 | NaN |
| A | 2002 | 1 |
| B | 1991 | 1 |
| B | 1992 | NaN |
| B | 1995 | NaN |
| B | 1998 | NaN |
| B | 2001 | 1 |
| B | 2002 | NaN |

I want to do forward fill by group and conditional on the value of column 'Year':  forward fill missing value until the 'Year' is more than five years apart.
For example, the value for group A in Year 1992 is 1, so the value for group A in 1995 should be forward filled with 1 since 1995-1992=3 <= 5; and the value for group A in 1997 should be forward filled with 1 since 1995-1992=3 <= 5; and the value for group A in 1998 should not be forward filled with 1 since 1998-1992=6 > 5.

The dataset I want is as follows:

| Group | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1990 | NaN |
| A | 1992 | 1 |
| A | 1995 | 1 |
| A | 1997 | 1 |
| A | 1998 | NaN |
| A | 2001 | NaN |
| A | 2002 | 1 |
| B | 1991 | 1 |
| B | 1992 | 1 |
| B | 1995 | 1 |
| B | 1998 | NaN |
| B | 2001 | 1 |
| B | 2002 | 1 |

Comment: Have you ever had a chance to test the approaches below?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a double [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) and mask with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
# identify rows within 5 of the previous non-NA value
m = (df['Year'].where(df['Value'].notna())
     .groupby(df['Group']).ffill()
     .rsub(df['Year']).le(5)
    )

# groupby.ffill and mask
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].ffill().where(m)
```

Output:

```
   Group  Year  Value
0      A  1990    NaN
1      A  1992    1.0
2      A  1995    1.0
3      A  1997    1.0
4      A  1998    NaN
5      A  2001    NaN
6      A  2002    1.0
7      B  1991    1.0
8      B  1992    1.0
9      B  1995    1.0
10     B  1998    NaN
11     B  2001    1.0
12     B  2002    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cummax` to identify 5-year ranges:

```
x = df['Year'].mask(df['Value'].notna(), df['Year'] + 5).groupby(df['Group']).cummax()

df['Value'] = df.groupby([df['Group'], x])['Value'].ffill()
```

Result:

```
   Group  Year  Value
0      A  1990    NaN
1      A  1992    1.0
2      A  1995    1.0
3      A  1997    1.0
4      A  1998    NaN
5      A  2001    NaN
6      A  2002    1.0
7      B  1991    1.0
8      B  1992    1.0
9      B  1995    1.0
10     B  1998    NaN
11     B  2001    1.0
12     B  2002    1.0
```